# Binding attributes in arbitrary class with sun's JAXB-Impl

Tags: java, xml, binding, jaxb, jaxb2

I have this xml sample:

```
<book id="1" isbn="0470743972" title="Data Mining Techniques in CRM: Inside Customer Segmentation" subject="Machine Learning"
            publishDate="2010-3-1" publisherId="1" rating="4.8">
            <authors>
                <author id="1" />
                <author id="2" />
            </authors>
        </book>
```

I need to map this to un annotated class. These classes are JPA annotated but not JAXB. I understand that this would work by default if the attributes are elements. But in this case, some work needs to be done. So my question is, Is this possible with JAXB-Impl (not MOXy) ? And if yes, where do I start and what do I need to customize. I looked into extending XmlAdapter, but couldn't find examples, about to do this. I appreciate any hint.

Comment: Are you trying to map to an XML attribute without using `@XmlAttribute`?

Comment: Yes! exactly. Is this possible with JAXB ? And if yes, how do I start ??
And if possible the list of child elements as a list !

Comment: Why can't you add the necessary JAXB annotations?

Comment: I can not do this. The whole binding is required to load the data from XML files. I can not add JAXB annotations just for this reason. Additionally, I have and expecting a lot of these entities.
An alternative solution would be to use SAX to load the data into these beans. Or I can transform the xml with XSLT before creating the entities. Before considering another solution, I wanted to know if it's possible with JAXB or not. And how to start, if it's possible.